# jQuery: trigger a hover event from another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, bind

When you hover over one `<div>`, I want an `<a>` on a separate part of the page to be "hovered" on also.

```
<div class="initiator">
</div>
<div>
   <a class="receiver href="#">Touch the div and I get hovered!</a>
</div>
```

I've tried this jQuery, but it doesn't trigger the `<a>`'s hover CSS.

```
$(".initiator").hover(function(){
   $(".receiver").hover();
   console.log("div was hovered");
});
```

Comment: `doesn't trigger the <a>'s hover CSS.` likely an issue within your css that isn't specific enough

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.initiator').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('.receiver').trigger(e.type);
})
```

It will apply the same triggers for the receiver as the initiator receives for both mouseenter and mouseleave. Note that:

```
.hover(over, out)
```

is just a high-level variant of:

```
.on('mouseenter', over).on('mouseleave', out)
```

so using that information you can be more precise when binding and triggering mouse events.

As noted in the comment, you can also use:

```
$('.initiator').hover(function(e) {
    $('.receiver').trigger(e.type);
})
```

There are lots more to read here: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: This is the way to do it, assuming we're talking about bound handlers, and assuming all `.receiver` elements should be triggered. Using `.hover()` would work here too, but naming the events is better IMO.

Comment: Yes, `.hover` works too, but I also think it’s usage logic is confusing when using only one argument.

Comment: actually `mouseenter` event don't force element to a hover state, so in my case this does not force css rule `:hover` so css don't get affected, and that's what i wanted it to do.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like-:

```
$(".initiator").hover(function(){
   $(".receiver").addClass('hover');
   console.log("div was hovered");
}, function(){
   $(".receiver").removeClass('hover');
});
```

And now you can have a class that holds the css rules.

Comment: `.trigger('hover')` isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "hovered", but assuming you have some CSS defined for `.receiver:hover` pseudo class I would suggest to move them to the separate CSS class `.hover` and use jQuery `toggleClass` function.

Here is a quick example that makes link text bold when you move mouse over the div - http://jsfiddle.net/Pharaon/h29bh/

```
$(".initiator").hover(function(){
  $(".receiver").toggleClass("hover");
  console.log("div was hovered");
});​
```

Comment: `$(".receiver").toggleClass("hover", event.type === 'mouseenter');` would be a little safer.

Answer (score 0):

`hover()` is a jQuery method that ties together `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events

try

```
$(this).find('.receiver').mouseenter()
```

Or

```
 $(this).find('.receiver').trigger('mouseenter')
```

However you will likely have far better results adding a class to the `a` tag and adding a new css rule.

```
 $(this).find('.receiver').toggleClass('hoverClass')
```

Comment: You could do `.trigger(event.type)` to align both event types.