# on click call hover/mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have fixed sidebar navigation bar, it works on hover but I want to open first menu by clicking on collapse button. similar working like hover on menu 1. I have already tried following methods .

**[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/13ddpfw7/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn1', function () {
    console.log('btn 1');
    //$('.imFirst  a').trigger('mouseenter');
    //$('.imFirst  a').trigger('mouseover');
    //$('.imFirst  a').trigger('hover');
    $('.imFirst a ').mouseenter()
    //$('.imFirst a ').mouseover()
    $('.imFirst   a').toggleClass('hover');

});

$(document).on('click', '.btn2', function () {
    console.log('btn 2');
   //$('.imFirst  ').trigger('mouseenter');
   //$('.imFirst  ').trigger('hover');
   //$('.imFirst  ').trigger('mouseover');
   $('.imFirst  ').mouseenter();
   //$('.imFirst  ').mouseover();
    $('.imFirst  ').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: trigger a hover event from another element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325519/jquery-trigger-a-hover-event-from-another-element)

Comment: Why you don't add a class to the menu you want to show when you click on collapse button?

Answer (score 1):

You must add class, to rember your condition. I am change your example 
[jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cobalt90/13ddpfw7/1/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn2', function () {
$('.imFirst').addClass('active');
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous answer I think your best bet is to add a class that is toggled when you click on the toggle button. The only difference with the previous answer is in the jsfiddle demo it works much better to add

```
       $('.imFirst').toggleClass('active');
```

so you are able to close the menu after opening it.

My rep is too low to add this as a comment.